# Finding quartiles from a cumulative distribution table

Tags: r, tibble

I am have a grouped tibble (tbl_df) containing cumulative frequency distribution from a combined dataset, where the column "size" contains the object size ranging from 30 to 800, the column "prop" contains the respective probability and the column cdf contains the cumulative frequency.

It is as follows:

| size | prop | cdf | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 0.00000832 | 0.00000832 | a |
| 31 | 0.0.00000849 | 0.0.0000168 | a |
| 32 | 0.0.00000885 | 0.0000257 | a |
| 33 | 0.0.00000918 | 0.0000348 | a |
| 34 | 0.0.00000938 | 0.0000442 | a |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 30 | 0.00000832 | 0.00000832 | b |
| 31 | 0.0.00000849 | 0.0.0000168 | b |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to find the quartiles using the cdf column. I understand this is a fairly easy question to do in real life and I am relatively new to R. I tried to use the summarize function but later on realize it did not take into account of the cdf and simply return the size order.

```
data %>% group_by(group) %>%
     summarize(Q1=quantile(size,probs=0.25),
          median=quantile(size,probs=0.5),
          Q3=quantile(size,probs=0.75)) %>% 
     dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 0)
```

Is there a function which I can use to summarize the data elegantly? And would it be possible to calculate the mean (i.e. sum (size x prob)/n as well?

Updated:
Thanks for the answer.

```
| group | cut_cdf | size |
| ---- | ---- | --- |
| a | (0.25,0.5] | 161 |
| a | (0.5,0.75] | 174 |
| a | (0.75,1] | 195 |
| b |(0.25,0.5] | 250 |
|...|...|...|
```

Comment: You could use summary(df) or summary(df$probs) . is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I am afraid summary(df) would not tell me which size the median is located at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
df |>
  mutate(
    cut_cdf = cut(cdf,
        breaks = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1),
        labels = c("Min", "Q25", "Q50", "Q75") # or your preferred labels
      )
  ) |>
  summarize(
    size = min(size),  # changed from size[1] to protect against out-of-order sizes
    .by = cut_cdf
  ) |>
  slice(-1) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = -cut_cdf,
    values_from = size
  )
```

In `mutate`, we're dividing up the data based on the cumulative cdf.  In `summarize`, we're taking the first value of size that falls into that category.  This will be the first value that is "just higher" than 0, 0.25, 0.5, etc.  Unless you want the 0th percentile, `slice(-1)` is removing that from the equation.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your help. I am wondering if my df is a grouped dataframe, i.e. i have an extra column specifying the group and i can groupby using ```df %>% group_by(group)``` can do still perform the code above? I tried to run it on R but it says ```Can't supply `.by` when `.data` is a grouped data frame.```

Comment: The `.by = cut_df` is the equivalent of calling `group_by(cut_df`) before and `ungroup()` after the summarize statement.  If you have other grouped variables, you can add `cut_cdf` to the set of group_by variables (e.g. `group_by(group, cut_df)`, or ungroup the data first and use `.by = c(group, cut_df) to avoid an ungroup after.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have managed to do it with ur ungroup and then .by = c(group, cut_df)  method. I have updated the output of the method u provided. Thank you again. I am wondering if i want to to present it nicely, as in a table showing group, Q1, median, Q3 as column, how would i elegantly extract the size?

Comment: I added a `pivot_wider` command that should give you group and the quantiles.  (Change the labels to match your needs - I didn't go back down to see your proposed labels).  There is a fancy way to get `pivot_wider` to get you the mean with the right set-up (see `unused_fn`) if it has `prop*size` for each group, but the chances I screw up the code without working from an actual data frame is almost 100%, so my recommendation is to calculate it from the data separately and use  `left_join` to merge them back together (technically, any of the joins would work in this case).